# How to convert the list of array to list of json object

Tags: javascript, json

i like to convert array to json object like this

```
var obj = [{item:'name1',start:new date()}, {item:'name2',start:new date()},{item:'name3',start:new date()}]
```

i am using single dimension array means is working fine. check this link http://jsfiddle.net/H4ezf/1/

```
 var objectArray= {};    
 objectArray['title']='All Day Event';
 objectArray['start']=new Date(y, m, 1);
 console.log(JSON.stringify(objectArray));
```

output as : `{"title":"All Day Event","start":"2012-06-30T18:30:00.000Z"}`

but i try to convert list of array to list json object using json stringify like this

```
var objectArray= {};    
objectArray[0]['title']='name1';
objectArray[0]['start']=new Date();
objectArray[1]['title']='name2';
objectArray[1]['start']=new Date();
console.log(JSON.stringify(objectArray));
```

it not working. what i am wrong here.
Please any one can help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var objectArray= [];
objectArray[0] = {}
objectArray[0]['title']='name1';
objectArray[0]['start']=new Date();
objectArray[1] = {}
objectArray[1]['title']='name2';
objectArray[1]['start']=new Date();
console.log(JSON.stringify(objectArray));​
```

Comment: Thank for your answer its working fine. i post this link for others http://jsfiddle.net/H4ezf/2/ - this one i need

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do this:

```
var objectArray= {};    
objectArray[0]['title']='name1';
```

as `objectArray[0]` does not exist yet. There is no array at that index and therefor you cannot add a string at an index. You have do declare the array first. The rest of your code works just fine.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HpLZp/)

Answer (score 1):

try it like this:

```
var objectArray = [];
objectArray[0] = {};
objectArray[0]['title'] = 'name1';
objectArray[0]['start'] = new Date();
```